# Struggling to get a strategy I'm building to take trades in backtester

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Long time trader, new coder here just working my way through learning pinescript.

I've built a simple 20 EMA strategy just to try to understand how the strategies work and am stumped as to why I'm not getting any trades in backtester.

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("20SMA test", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, use_bar_magnifier = true, default_qty_value = 1, initial_capital = 5000, max_bars_back = 5000, commission_value = 1.29, commission_type = strategy.commission.cash_per_contract )


///USER INPUTS

EMA_LENGTH= input.int(defval= 20, title = "EMA Length")

stop = input.float(3, title="Stop")
target = input.float(10, title = "Target")

///trading target and stop logic

EMA = ta.ema(close, EMA_LENGTH)

LS = strategy.position_avg_price - stop
LT = strategy.position_avg_price + target

SS = strategy.position_avg_price + stop
ST = strategy.position_avg_price - target

///buy and sell logic

buy = (low<EMA and close > EMA) and close > open
sell = (high > EMA and close <EMA) and close < open

//strategy executions

barsSinceOpened = strategy.opentrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na

//enter long trade
if buy and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment = "Long")

//enter short trade
if sell and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.long, comment = "Short")

//manage long trade
if strategy.opentrades > 0 and strategy.position_size > 0 and barsSinceOpened > 0
    strategy.exit("long", from_entry="Long", stop = LS, limit = LT, comment = "Target/Stop- Long")

//manage short trade
if strategy.opentrades > 0 and strategy.position_size < 0 and barsSinceOpened > 0
    strategy.exit("Short", from_entry="Short", stop = SS, limit = ST, comment = "Target/Stop- Short")

//color EMA plot 

plot(EMA, color = EMA> EMA[1] ? color.green : color.red, linewidth=2)
```